# Is there a proxy server alternative that works on local IP addresses for getting around CORS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, same-origin-policy

I have had success getting around CORS for AJAX requests to public IP addresses through the use of proxy servers: effectively making the request from the server and returning the response with different headers. Is there something similar that would work on local IP addresses from a server hosted off-site? I do not have access to modify any of the code on this local IP.

Comment: Take a look at nginx proxy server: https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx

Answer (score 1):

You can't proxy data from a computer you can't make a connection to.

If both computers were on the same network (e.g. via a VPN) then this would work in exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Are there any alternatives to a proxy to get around CORS?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable CORS in browser if this helps, or add CORS headers using extensions